# How come for a batch of newly imported products the URL structure is different than our normal configuration?

Tags: product, multistore, configuration, url, store-view

I imported some 34 simple products to our admin store, base site, via [MageBees' Import/Export Products extension](https://www.magebees.com/magento-import-export-simple-products-configurable-products-bundle-products-group-products-downloadable-products.html), as I often do. The problem is that their URLs are rendering as `default/catalog/product/view/id/13578/s/24-round-granite-white-plastic-folding-table/category/990/` when all our products' permalinks are normally in the form of `default/48-round-bi-fold-granite-white-plastic-folding-table.html`.

This was a problem when they were first imported but unfortunately I have not an accurate log of the details of that scenario. They were since deleted and re-imported. I think it was because I had imported them to the main store and not the admin, so all the default values were different or something, and had something to do with the status setting in each view...

In both default and store views status = Enabled, although in store view it's also set to use the default view value. If disabled in either view, product is inaccessible in the frontend. When I in store view UNSET use_default status, at first it appeared to fix the issue and the URL structure reverted back to normal; so I applied this to all of them and for whatever Magical Mystery Magento reason (like 666 MMM) it fixed about half of them seemingly totally arbitrarily among the lot. *Then,* on ones resolved, I tried setting status = use_default[] and the URL *stayed proper*. So it didn't change back to the other/wrong structure/format.

To me this makes little sense and I'm at a loss as to what to try. I've tried clearing the cache. Any ideas?